# Spring Data Neo4j 4.x and sdn-university: Neo4jTemplate no autowire'ing

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I am upgrading our application, which is modelled closely after `sdn-university`, from Spring Data Neo4j 3.x to Spring Data Neo4j 4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. When adding an autowire'd instance of Neo4jTemplate, the following exception is thrown upon startup:

> ... Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.template.Neo4jTemplate
>   school.service.UserServiceImpl.template; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.data.neo4j.template.Neo4jTemplate] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:571)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
>     ... 21 more ...

To validate the results, I've taken the latest `sdn-university` -- which also now makes use of SDN4.x 4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT -- from https://github.com/neo4j-examples/sdn4-university and have modified the StudentServiceImpl to include an autowire'd instance of Neo4jTemplate. Upon issuing a `mvn clean spring-boot:run -U`, the error, as seen within our application, is reproduced.

What needs to be changed to `sdn-university` to successfully make use of a Neo4jTemplate?

Answer (score 3):

The reason this doesn't work in SDN4 is because `Neo4jTemplate` and its interface, `Neo4jOperations`, are both annotated with `@Repository`.  Therefore, Spring makes a proxy of the `Neo4jTemplate` class which doesn't auto-wire correctly because of a type mismatch.

The best approach is to code against the `Neo4jOperations` interface instead of the `Neo4jTemplate` class.  Whether this will be the case in the final release of SDN4 is still undecided, although I'd always favour coding against interfaces anyway, personally.

You may also need to declare `Neo4jOperations` as the return type of your bean factory method:

```
@Bean
public Neo4jOperations neo4jTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new Neo4jTemplate(getSession());
}
```

Comment: I've replaced our single instance of Neo4jTemplate with Neo4jOperations in both our application and sdn-university and each application still fails to start with the same error and stacktrace. If I understand you correctly, declaring an '@Autowired private NeoOperations neoOperations' could/would/should work, correct?

Comment: Yes, changing the autowired field type to `Neo4jOperations` should do the trick.  What does your @Bean method look like in your configuration class?

Comment: I was missing the above @Bean definition that you provided above. Once I added that things are now working as expected. Thanks.